# Где и как хранится адрес переменной?

Tags: java, ооп, память, виртуальная-машина, адрес

Господа, занимаюсь по Java Rush, и там присутствует такая фраза: "Адресом переменной считается адрес первой ячейки выделенного под нее блока памяти." [image: скрин]
 Т. е. если, например, под переменную `int x` выделяется 4 байта (ячейки памяти), то адрес этой переменной будет хранится в первом байте? Но ведь все 4 байта отводятся **строго** под число. Тогда что же получается, под переменную `x` на самом деле выделяется 5 байт, чтобы в первом байте хранить её адрес?
[Link](https://javarush.ru/quests/lectures/questsyntaxpro.level02.lecture04) на саму лекцию.
Или как с объектом класса String. Переменная типа String хранит в себе адрес первой ячейки блока памяти, выделенного под сам объект этого класса. Но ведь перменная с адресом объекта должна в себе же хранить и свой адрес тоже.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Например переменная `str` хранит адрес первой ячеки выделенного под объект типа `String` блока памяти: **G13**. Но получается что в первой ячейке самой переменной `str`должен хранится её собственный адрес: **B13**.
Объясните подробно новичку этот момент. Пожалуйста.

Comment: не думаю что для java это важная информация, но в целом да логика такая что сами адреса тоже где-то хранятся только не рядом с выделенной памятью а в другом специально отведенном месте.

Comment: Если знаете ссылку на подробное (а лучше подробнейшее) описание этих моментов - поделитесь, пожалуйста. Хотя конечно, в случае с Java, можно особо не вникать и просто идти дальше по курсу.

Comment: да в этом случае идти дальше будет разумнее, нет смысла вникать в то на что нельзя повлиять, а польза учитывания этого момента в java тоже сомнительна, если найду ссылку скину

Comment: https://tproger.ru/blogs/jvm-insides/ вот тут вроде неплохо описано

Comment: @DaniilLoban, imho этот материал (о структуре файлов в JVM) запутает ТС еще больше. Правильный ответ -- адреса переменных хранятся прямо в скомпилированной программе (обычно не  в абсолютном виде, а в виде смещений)

Comment: @work8play, если хотите серьезно разбираться, то начните свое знакомство с IT с какого-нибудь ассемблера. Далее все встанет на свои места

Answer (score 3):

"Адресом считается" и "адрес хранится" это совершенно разные вещи. Хранятся адреса переменных совсем в другом месте.

К примеру,  я живу по адресу ул.Пушкина, д.2, но запись об этом адресе хранится не там, а в паспортном столе. Примерно так и с переменными.

Да и хранить адрес переменной по адресу переменной довольно спорная идея - ведь тогда для того, чтобы узнать адрес переменной нужно будет знать адрес этой переменной :)

Еще одна аналогия: библиотека. Книги хранятся внизу в хранилище на полках, но информация о том, на какой именно находится та или иная книга, содержится в каталоге (на карточках или в базе данных). Так и с переменными - они сами хранятся в одном разделе памяти, а информация о том, в какой именно ячейке хранится та или иная переменная, в другом, специально для этого отведенном. А как это реализовано технически, в принципе, уже и неважно, если только не писать особые узкоспециализированные программы.

Answer (score 1):

Содержимое "лекции" мало пересекается с реальностью. В контексте java какая-либо адресация памяти не предусмотрена! У переменных или полей встроенных или ссылочных типов никаких адресов нет. При *выполнении* программы соответствующие данные действительно на каких-то этапах могут оказываться где-то в оперативной памяти (а могут и не оказываться), однако когда, как и где именно - глядя на исходный код программы на java ничего определенного сказать нельзя. Собственно одна из основных особенностей java - автоматическая работа с памятью - как раз и направлена на полное абстрагирование исходного кода от непосредственной работы с адресами и других аспектов размещения данных в памяти вычислительного устройства.

Answer (score 0):

Это информация вначале обучения явно будет лишняя и лишь запутает Вас. Java тем и хороша, что самостоятельно оптимизирует место, чистит мусор и тд (не всегда, но это понадобится потом). Если очень интересно, **[то вот хорошая статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/134102/)** по этому поводу на **хабре**, там всё сложнее.

Answer (score 0):

[Тут видео как ЦП обращается к RAM.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-knefdASOz8&t=1043s)
Если в двух словах то по адресной шине идет номер ячейки в памяти, а по шине данных считывание значения из памяти.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/764769)